# Is it possible to integrate joomla/wordpress with ruby on rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, wordpress, joomla, content-management-system

Is it possible to integrate joomla/wordpress with ruby on rails??? If not, can anyone suggest me some CMS tools for ruby on rails??

Comment: Did you have any success finding the right solution? I'm facing now a similar problema and looks like these answers are not helping..

Comment: Use a sub-path and a reverse-proxy to direct /blog to another host that is running Joomla/Wordpress.

Answer (score 2):

These concepts are different:

- Joomla and Wordpress are CMS frameworks in PHP
- Ruby-on-Rails is a web application framework in Ruby

Popular CMS in Ruby-on-Rails are:

- http://locomotivecms.com/
- http://refinerycms.com/

Answer (score 1):

About integration - not sure that it's even exists. 
About CMS - try refinery CMS - it's simple enough and can be extended by yourself.

Answer (score 1):

If you are interested in a CMS that has workflow of edit-review-approve pipeline, you can see [browserCMS](http://www.browsercms.org/)

Answer (score 1):

Your ruby on rails Api's can communicate with wordpress application with some predefine methods, methods are available in WP for fetching the api's data in json format.

Answer (score 0):

Yes It is possible. You can achieve this using [rubypress](https://github.com/zachfeldman/rubypress) gem. This gem provides you an interface for XML RPC API. If you want to upload featured image then refer my [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30367039/3962760) answer of stackoverflow.